# Is "it was the birth of a revolution" a metaphor?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Here is the full sentence for the first one: Using the money they had received from the PayPal buyout, Chen and Hurley decided to create YouTube, to make uploading and sharing videos online as easy as anyone could want. It was the birth of a revolution.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Please ask one question per question.  What have you found in your research on metaphors that is confusing or controversial?

Comment: Are you asking about "birth" or "revolution"?

Answer (score 1):

Most words in the language originated as metaphors, including *language*, *originate* and *metaphor*.

`The birth of a revolution` IS a metaphor but, like all metaphors involving birth, death, rise, fall and so on, it is now so commonplace that it has lost any power or magic it may have had and no longer sounds like one.

Answer (score 0):

It was a metaphor comparing birth to beginning, so literally it was the beginning of a revolution.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birth

Comment: But where were the guns and swords associated with a revolution?